# Puppeteer get cells in a row

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I need to scrape a table with puppeteer to get all cells (rows and cells).

Table is:

```
<table class="grilla" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_PlaceContent_gvConceptos" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr class="grilla_head" align="center">
                <th scope="col">Concepto</th><th scope="col">Empresa</th><th scope="col">Descripción</th><th scope="col">Haberes</th><th scope="col">Deducciones</th>
            </tr><tr class="grilla_item separador">
                <td align="center" style="font-size:10pt;">001</td><td align="center" style="font-size:10pt;">001</td><td style="font-size:10pt;">P.B.U - PRESTACION BASICA UNIVERSAL</td><td align="right" style="font-size:10pt;">8144,14</td><td align="right" style="font-size:10pt;"></td>
            </tr>
                

        </table>
```

I managed to get the html from table in a frame with this code:

```
// Get the username and password inputs
const browser = await Apify.launchPuppeteer();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("https://servicioscorp.anses.gob.ar/MiAnsesSitio/Sistemas/InvocaSistemas.aspx?IdMenu=10603");
// Login
await page.type('#Usuario', "user");
await page.type('#Clave',"key");
let n,x;
 for (n=0 ; n <= 3000 ; n++) { console.log(n)     }
await page.click('#Ingresar');
await page.waitForNavigation()
await page.click('#ctl00_MenuIzquierdo_rpt_MenuPadre_ctl05_lnk_Padre')
await page.click('#ctl00_MenuIzquierdo_rpt_MenuPadre_ctl05_rpt_MenuHijos_ctl02_lnk')
await page.waitForNavigation()
const frame = await page.frames().find(frame => frame.name() === 'ctl00_PlaceContent_icontenedor');
await frame.waitForSelector('#ctl00_PlaceContent_txtMes')
await frame.type('#ctl00_PlaceContent_txtMes','01');
await frame.type("#ctl00_PlaceContent_txtAnio","2021");
await frame.click("#ctl00_PlaceContent_btnConsultar");
await frame.waitForNavigation()
await frame.waitForSelector('#ctl00_PlaceContent_tlb_General_Grilla')
let element = await frame.$('#ctl00_PlaceContent_tlb_General_Grilla')
// Get inner text
const innerText = await frame.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#ctl00_PlaceContent_tlb_General_Grilla').innerText);
// Get inner HTML
const innerHTML = await frame.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#ctl00_PlaceContent_tlb_General_Grilla').innerHTML);
console.log(innerHTML)
console.log('Done.');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a lot going on here. It'd be helpful if you could point out exactly what part of the code things are going wrong for you. What output are you hoping to get, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

How to scrape a table content as a 2-dimensional array:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch(/* { headless: false, defaultViewport: null } */);

const html = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>`;

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return Array.from(
      document.querySelector('table').rows,
      row => Array.from(row.cells, cell => cell.innerText),
    );
  });
  console.log(data); // [ [ '1', '2' ], [ 'a', 'b' ] ]
} catch(err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```

Comment: Sorry, dont´t get anything on console

Comment: Do you use exactly this example or do you adapt it for your case?

Comment: No errors, just an empty console? That's strange. What Node.js, Chrome, and puppeteer versions do you use? How do you name the script and how do you run it?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it inside a function. Now works perfects. Thanks a lot!!!